# Finding max's from a column for all values on other column

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like this :

[image: MySQL table]

I want to find the id having max age from each skills in skills column. So the answer for this table will be Cooking->r1, Eating->r2 and Coding->r3.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'd recommend GROUP BY in a sub-query to find each skill's max age. Join with that result.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, GROUP BY gives skills and max(age) but I want the corresponding id from max(age).

Comment: As I said, JOIN your table with the GROUP BY result!

Comment: Just a note, as a naming convention I prefer column names in singularis, e.g. skill. (And table names in pluralis.)

Comment: You have no ties in your sample data.  If you have ties, how do you want them handled?  Display all ID's having that max age?  display the min(ID)?   Something else?

Answer (score 2):

Do a `GROUP BY` in a sub-query to find each skill's max age. `JOIN` with that result.

```
SELECT t.id, t.age, t.skills
FROM tablename t
join (select skills, max(age) as maxage
      from tablename
      GROUP BY skills) t2
    on t.skills = t2.skills and t.age = t2.maxage
```

**Note:** Ties will be included. (If there are two id's with same max age for a skill, both will be returned.)

Comment: Works for sample set, but if ties exist...

Comment: Ties will be included, of course. Don't you want those?